# How to bind dependency property to DataGridComboBoxColumn in UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties, datagridcomboboxcolumn

The XAML of my UserControl with name "Clinical_Protocol":

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="ClinicalProtocolDataGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems, ElementName=Clinical_Protocol}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Structure ID"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems, ElementName=Clinical_Protocol, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedStructureId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="RT ROI Type Code" 
                                    Binding="{Binding RtRoiInterpretedTypeCode}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="RT ROI Type Description"
                                    Binding="{Binding RtRoiInterpretedTypeDescription}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

The dependency property for `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid in the code behind:

```cs
internal ObservableCollection<ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem> DataGridItems
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem>)GetValue(DataGridItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DataGridItemsProperty, value); }
}

internal static readonly DependencyProperty DataGridItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DataGridItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem>),
                typeof(ClinicalProtocolView), new PropertyMetadata(null, DataGridItemsPropertyChangedCallback));

private static void DataGridItemsPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (ClinicalProtocolView)d;
    control.DataGridItems = (ObservableCollection<ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem>)e.NewValue;
}
```

The according `ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem` class:

```cs
public class ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem
{
    public string RtRoiInterpretedTypeCode { get; }
    public string RtRoiInterpretedTypeDescription { get; }
    public object SelectedStructureId { get; set; }

    public ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem(string rtRoiInterpretedTypeCode, string rtRoiInterpretedTypeDescription)
    {
        RtRoiInterpretedTypeCode = rtRoiInterpretedTypeCode ??
                                       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rtRoiInterpretedTypeCode));
        RtRoiInterpretedTypeDescription = rtRoiInterpretedTypeDescription ??
                                              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rtRoiInterpretedTypeDescription));
    }
}
```

And finally the dependency property `ComboBoxItems`:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> ComboBoxItems
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>)GetValue(ComboBoxItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ComboBoxItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>),
        typeof(ClinicalProtocolView), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>(),
                    PropertyChangedCallback));

private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (ClinicalProtocolView)d;
    control.ComboBoxItems = (ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>)e.NewValue;
}
```

I try to populate both dependency properties with the following:

```cs
private void AddSomeComboBoxItems()
{
    ComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>
    {
        new ComboBoxItem(){Content = "S1",  HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center},
        new ComboBoxItem(){Content = "S2",  HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center},
        new ComboBoxItem(){Content = "S3",  HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center},
}

private void AddSomeRows()
{
    var items = new List<ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem>
    {
        new ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem("PTV", "Description of PTV, and it is a very long description!"),
        new ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem("OAR", "Description of OAR, and it is a very long description!"),
    };

    DataGridItems = new ObservableCollection<ClinicalProtocolDataGridItem>(items);
}
```

When I import it into a WPF application I get the following:

[image: Combo Box Example picture]

And the error message:
`DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource IEnumerable Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.`            
[image: Error message]

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) says that it is possible to bind a collection of `ComboBoxItem`. What am I missing? I don't want to have a static resource, because the combo box items might change during runtime.

Comment: The very idea of creating a collection of ComboBoxItems is very bad.
ComboBoxItem is a UI element. And any UI element can only be displayed in one place. Even just using a single ComboBox with a ComboBoxItem collection does not work correctly. But you want to set this collection to several ComboBoxes. See the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348884/wpf-tooltip-binding-the-content-of-comboboxitem-and-when-hover-the-comboboxit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataGridColumn is a simple DependencyObject, not a UI element. It is not embedded in the visual tree and cannot get values from it. The ElementName and FindAncestor bindings will not work in it.

You need to get the collection into a static resource and only then get it from there for the DataGridColumn.

```xml
<DataGrid Name="ClinicalProtocolDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems, ElementName=Clinical_Protocol}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <!--Using a CollectionViewSource as a proxy to create a "static link".-->
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Key="comboBoxItems"
            Source="{Binding ComboBoxItems, ElementName=Clinical_Protocol}"/>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn
            Header="Structure ID"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource comboBoxItems}}"
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedStructureId, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**P.S.** Please note my comment on your question. I explain there why even after a successful binding to such a source, the ComboBoxs may still work incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you! So it seems that a DataGrid is not the right choice for what I want to achieve, right? I want the user to select a structure ID from a Collection of structure IDs and thereby map it to a RT ROI Type. Is there anything else that I can use than DataGrid?

Comment: @Anno , The problem is not with the DataGrid. You need to set the collection not with a ComboBoxItem, but simply with the strings: "S1", "S2", "S3".

Comment: Okay I changed the `ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>` to `ObservableCollection<string>` and I added your code. I still get some errors that I do not understand: `Property "Source" was not found on Object of type "ListCollectionView"`

Comment: @Anno, Weird. Did you copy my code in full? I created a short example myself - everything seems to work.
Try changing the binding to something like `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource comboBoxItems}}"` or like this `ItemsSource="{StaticResource comboBoxItems}"`.

Comment: This one was it: `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource comboBoxItems}}"`. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've corrected my answer to reflect what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove dependency property `ComboBoxItems` you don't need it, but add to the code behind a data provider  method for your combo boxes:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> GetCbxSource()
{
    return new ObservableCollection<string>
    {
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
    };
}
```

Then in XAML you can declare a data provider and later use it like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="cbxData" MethodName="GetCbxSource" ObjectInstance="{x:Reference Clinical_Protocol}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DataGrid Name="ClinicalProtocolDataGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems, ElementName=Clinical_Protocol}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Structure ID"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source= {StaticResource cbxData}}"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedStructureId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RT ROI Type Code" 
                                    Binding="{Binding RtRoiInterpretedTypeCode}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RT ROI Type Description"
                                    Binding="{Binding RtRoiInterpretedTypeDescription}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```